# Can i connect motorola rs507 as a bluetooth peripheral in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Can i connect a [motorola RS507 ring scanner](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Wearable+Computers/RS507_US-EN) as a bluetooth peripheral to my iOS app. If yes how can i do that? I currently use device camera to scan barcodes and i want to add this scanner as an option to scan barcodes. Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: Apparently there is a link for a iOS firmware: https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/ReleaseNotes/Release%20Notes%20-%20RS507%20firmware%20with%20iOS%20support%20%20-%20%20PAAACC07-005-R01.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zebra Technologies acquired Motorola Solutions Enterprise Business in October 2014, you can find more information about this product on [Zebra website](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/wearable-computers/rs5071.html).
As Larme pointed out, [there's a FW available for the RS507 to setup the device using HID Bluetooth Profile and use it with iOS devices](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=93556&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3Drs507).
Just keep in mind that access to this firmware requires a support contract after 90days of buying the device.
You can reach out to your local Zebra office for more informations.

Comment: Thank you , that was helpful. But can you help on how can use the scanned barcode in the app. Since it gets connected as a bluetooth keyboard, how do i use the barcode string .

Comment: Depends from your app. Usually on Zebra scanners you can assign prefix and postfix to a barcode, so you can use those to identify that the keypresses are coming from the reader. Take a look at the [RS507 Reference Guide](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=90140&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3DRS507) on how to setup these parameters.